# Delete duplicate rows based on 2 column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, duplicates, delete-row, worksheet-function

I have a sheet with 8 columns A to H and over 1000 rows. I would like to delete all rows that has duplicate values in column A and check if column H is an empty (zero value) cell.

If the column H is empty then delete the entire row, not the row that has a value in column H.

Example -
Row 1 has ABC in column A and MyText in column H
Row 2 has ABC in column A and no value in column H
Delete row 2 as the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this formula in `I1`:

```
=AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A1)>1,H1=0)
```

Then delete only rows where in `I` column you get `TRUE`

---

**Detailed steps**

1. Create the formula:

[image]

2. Create 1 row at the top
3. Select everything including the first row
4. "Data" -> "Filter"
5. Leave only `TRUE` on column `I`
6. Select those rows:

[image]

7. "Home" -> "Delete"

[image]

Comment: Wont this delete the row and all its duplicates?

Comment: @OwenKelvin - Thank you. I have updated the answer with detailed steps

Comment: Thank you very much, this did the trick - much appreciated!